# Ubuntu kernel doesn't boot up right

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I compiled a Ubuntu 15.04 kernel last night and installed it this morning. It showed up fine in my grub but when I tried to boot it, it booted me to my Ubuntu 14.04 instaed. What is going on? Also, during the installation, there were four dependency errors:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-cloud-tools- 3.19.0-22-generic: linux-cloud-tools-3.19.0-22-generic depends on linux-cloud-tools-3.19.0-22; however: Package linux-cloud-tools-3.19.0-22 is not installed.

    dpkg: error processing package linux-cloud-tools-3.19.0-22-generic (--install): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-3.19.0-22-generic: linux-tools-3.19.0-22-generic depends on linux-tools-3.19.0-22; however: Package linux-tools-3.19.0-22 is not installed.

    dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-3.19.0-22-generic (--install): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Do these errors have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you install? Where did you get the installation image from? Are there any other issues besides these error messages?

Comment: I compiled my own ubuntu 15.04 kernel and installed it, so there was no installation image.

Comment: Why do you install cloud-tools? Linux-tools and cloud-tools are not needed in most cases. You either install unneeded deb packages or install not all of them. If you need cloud-tools, then install linux-tools too. You can install just image and headers debs in most cases. But these errors do not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Linux-tools and cloud-tools are not needed in most cases. You either install unneeded deb packages or install not all of them. If you need cloud-tools, then install linux-tools too. You can install just image and headers debs in most cases. But these errors do not really matter.

If there were no other errors and `uname -r` shows the correct kernel version, you installed it right.